# Can't install uwsgi on ubuntu

Tags: install, apt

```
root@ip-10-194-97-94:~# apt-get install uwsgi

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  uwsgi: Depends: uwsgi-python2.6 (>= 0.9.6.5-0ubuntu1~lucid1) or
                  uwsgi-python3.1 (>= 0.9.6.5-0ubuntu1~lucid1)
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: [Ubuntu doesn't ship `uwsgi`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=uwsgi). What source did you add to get the package? If you followed instructions on a web page, link to it. Post the relevant lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the [uwsgi launchpad repo](https://launchpad.net/uwsgi).

It is not obvious, but you shouldn't be touching the `uwsgi` package, but use the `uwsgi-python` package instead.

Explanation is given [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/uwsgi/+bug/742109/comments/1), they are transferring from `uwsgi` to the name `uwgsi-python`.